# PHP Foreach Loop and DOMNodeList

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to determine the end of a foreach loop that is seeded with a collection of DOMNodeList.  Currently, I am using a for loop would like to avoid having a 'magic' number there.  I do know there are only going to be 8 columns, but I would like the code me generic for other applications.

Is it possible to convert this to a Foreach loop?  I have tried the end() and next() functions, but they are not returning any data and I suspect that they only work on arrays and not this DOMNodeList collection.

The code is building a CSV file without the trailing ','

Current output is:

"Value 1","Value 2","Value 3","Value 4","Value 5","Value 6","Value 7","Value 8"

Here is an example of code:

```
$cols = $row->getElementsByTagName("td");
$printData = true;

// Throw away the header row
if ($isFirst && $printData) {
   $isFirst = false;
   continue;
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
   $output = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//IGNORE", $cols->item($i)->nodeValue);
   $output2 = trim($output);
   if ($i == 8) {
      // Last Column
      echo "\"" . $output2 . "\"" . "\n";
   } else {
      echo "\"" . $output2 . "\"" . ",";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
$cols->length
```

To retrieve the number of items in a DOMNodeList.

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php

Edit:
If you change you're code to this, you don't have to worry about the trailing comma, or the length:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($cols as $item) {
   $output = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//IGNORE", $item->nodeValue);
   $output2 = trim($output);

   $output[] = '"' . $output2 . '"';
}
$outputstring = implode(',', $output);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$cols->length
```

Should give you the number of items in the list

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $cols->length; $i++) {

// ...

if ($i == $cols->length - 1) {
// last column
```